# help with inverse function in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: inverse

$F(x,y)=(x^2+2y^2,2x^2+y^2)$, and $A=\{(x,y):x>0,y>0\}$

I need to show $F(A)=\{(u,v):0<u/2<v<2u\}$

I also need to find what is $G(=F^{-1}):B\rightarrow A$

For the first question I misunderstand what it is asking me.. I think if I choose u = 4, v=2 the inequality does not hold.  What is the meaning of this?

For the second question, do I need to find the inverse functions, where B is the new domain of the inverse function?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you find a pair $(x,y)$ such that $F(x,y) = (4,2)$? If you cannot, then you can't choose $u=4, v=2$.

Comment: @Jonny You make an excellent point.  So to show this for the general case do I set u to be $x^2+2y^2$, and v to be $2x^2+y^2$?

Comment: Yes. Then you must demonstrate that a pair is in $F(A)$ if and only if it is in $\{(u,v): 0<u/2:v:2u\}$

Comment: @Jonny Can I trouble you with the second question?  I am guessing I need to find an inverse function, but haven't ever attempted this in $\mathbb R^2$.  Any hints you can give me?

Comment: I think a lot of the work in solving question 1 will help with question 2.

Answer (score 1):

Given
$$\begin{gathered}
  F:{\mathbb{R}^2} \to {\mathbb{R}^2} \hfill \\
  F(x,y) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1&2 \\ 
  2&1 
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x^2}} \\ 
  {{y^2}} 
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x^2} + 2{y^2}} \\ 
  {2{x^2} + {y^2}} 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Then:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x^2}} \\ 
  {{y^2}} 
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{1}{3}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&2 \\ 
  2&{ - 1} 
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  u \\ 
  v 
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{1}{3}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - u + 2v} \\ 
  {2u - v} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
That is:
$$\begin{gathered}
  x = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\sqrt { - u + 2v}  \hfill \\
  y = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\sqrt {2u - v}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Now we have a map:
$$\begin{gathered}
  G:{\mathbb{R}^2} \to {\mathbb{R}^2} \hfill \\
  G(u,v) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt { - u + 2v} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {2u - v} } 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
with property:
$$\begin{gathered}
  G(F(x,y)) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt { - ({x^2} + 2{y^2}) + 2(2{x^2} + {y^2})} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {2({x^2} + 2{y^2}) - (2{x^2} + {y^2})} } 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt { - {x^2} - 2{y^2} + 4{x^2} + 2{y^2}} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {2{x^2} + 4{y^2} - 2{x^2} - {y^2})} } 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt {3{x^2}} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {3{y^2}} } 
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt 3 x} \\ 
  {\sqrt 3 y} 
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  x \\ 
  y 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

But that means:$$(G \circ F)(x,y) = (x,y)$$

$G$ is called the inverse map for $F$.

And the other truth:
$$(F \circ G)(u,v) = (u,v)$$
works the same way.$F$ is called the inverse map for $G$